# Pattern Printing-Where am I going wrong in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, logic

I wrote a program to print a `N x N` square pattern with alternate 0's and 1's. For eg. A 5 x 5 square would looks like this:

[image]

I used the following code-

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int i, n;
  cin >> n; //number of rows (and columns) in the n x n matrix
  for(i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)
  {
    cout << " " << i%2;
    if(i%n == 0)
    cout << "\n";
  }

  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

This code works fine for odd numbers but for even numbers it prints the same thing in each new line and not alternate pattern.For 4 it prints this-

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The most obviously wrong thing is a complete lack of indentation and a bracing style that's best described as anarchy. Please, clean up this code.

Comment: @tadman I am an absolute beginner.I have no idea how to do that correctly...

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Can debuggers help to find logical errors in my code?

Comment: Yes.  That is partly what they are built for.

Comment: It's fine to be a beginner, but without reference material you're going to be hopelessly lost. A good place to start is the [Programming C++ Book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) by the creator of C++. From there you can get a grasp of the syntax using the examples, and then find a more specific style guide that helps keep things in order. There's a lot of [bracing styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) to choose from.

Comment: @tadman Are indentations in C++ only useful for making the code more redable and easy to grasp unlike Python where indentations form a part of syntax?Can I indent in any way I like that makes the code easy to read or is there a specific way to do it?

Comment: The indentation style has no bearing on the code's meaning to the compiler, but it can have *significant* meaning to the coder. C++ is a wild beast at the best of times, so anything you can do to make the flow in your code as clear as possible helps considerably, *especially* when you're asking others for help and they need to quickly understand what you're doing.

Comment: tadman, aesthetics is not the problem here.. and should also be secondary in learning how to code. 
@soham, I can assure you your code correctly alternates printing 0 and 1. I am also a huge fan of debugging things on paper (more mathematician like) , maybe just write down your stream of 0, 1 in one row, and in another your current 'i'. The error should then become quite apparent. 
Nonetheless sooner or later you should have followed through all the advice tadman gave you, it is definitely a big step becoming better as a programmer.

Comment: Are you sure you posted code that you compiled and tested?  What compiler are you using?  (1) Replace `<iostream.h>` with `<iostream>` (2) Remove `fflush(stdin)`! (3) Comments are `//` *not* `\\\`.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Maybe I use an outdated version of DevC++ but if I remove the .h from the header it shows "cin undeclared (first use this function)"...and why should I remove the fflush() part?

Comment: This would be much easier if you used two `for` loops instead of one.

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you talking about the method used in the second answer posted just now?

Comment: It is obvious that you're trying to learn right now, I'm going to refrain from giving too much advice since doing your own thinking is more productive.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks sir...

Comment: " _why should I remove the fflush() part?_ " --> See comp.lang.c FAQ question 12.26a

The error you get when you replace iostream.h with iostream is because `cin` is now in a _namespace_ called `std`.  The idea is that if you write your own function say `PatternPrint`, it won't be a problem if the C++ library also has a function named `PatternPrint` in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way to iterate over matrix is using loop in another loop.

I think this code will be helpful for you:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        cout<<" "<< (j + i) % 2;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

where `n` is number of rows, `i` and `j` are ints.

Try to understand why and how it works.

Comment: I don't think `j % n` is necessary as it is only true in the last iteration of the loop; just put it after the inner loop

Comment: Of course, you are right, thanks. My bad. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a beginner programmer, then I suggest (no offence) not trying to be too clever with your methodology; the main reason why your code is not working is (apart from various syntax errors) a *logic error* - as pointed out by blauerschluessel.

Just use two loops, one for rows and one for columns:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        cout << " " << ((row % 2) ^ (col % 2));
    cout << "\n";
}
```

---

EDIT: since you wanted a one-loop solution, a good way to do so would be to set a `flip` flag which handles the difference between even and odd `n`:

```
bool flip = false;
int nsq = n * n;
for (int i = 1; i <= nsq; i++)
{
   cout << " " << (flip ^ (i % 2));
   if (i % n == 0) {
       if (n % 2 == 0) flip = !flip;
       cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah...I know the conventional method for creating patterns using two loops (nested)... but I was trying to do something different...

Comment: @soham it's good that you are setting yourself a challenge; but in this particular case your problem is actually not programming related at all

Comment: Maybe...Thanks by the way

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it isn't working and creating is because of your logic. To fix this you need to change what the code does. The easiest way to handle that is to think of what it does and compare that to what you want it to do. This sounds like it is for an assignment so we could give you the answer but then you would get nothing from our help so I've writen this answer to guide you to the logic of solving it yourself.

Lets start with what it does.

Currently it is going to print 0 or 1 `n*n` times. You have a counter named `i` that will increment every time starting from 0 and going to `(n*n)-1`. If you were to print this number `i` you would get the following table for `n=5`

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Now you currently check if the value `i` is odd or even `i%2` and this makes the value 0 or 1. Giving you the following table

```
1  0  1  0  1
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1
```

Now in the case of `n=4` your counter `i` would print out to give you a table

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Now if you print out the odd or even pattern you get

```
1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0
```

This pattern diffrence is because of the changing pattern of printed numbers due to the shape of the square or more accurately matrix you are printing. To fix this you need to adjust the logic of how you determine which number to print because it will only work for matrixes that have odd widths.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one more parameter to print the value. Below mentioned code has the updated `for loop` which you are using:

```
int num = 0;
for(i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)
{
    num = !num;
    std::cout << " " << num;
    if(i%n == 0) {
        std::cout << "\n";      
        num = n%2 ? num : !num;  

    }
}
```

The complete compiled code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, n, num = 0;
    std::cin >> n; //number of rows (and columns) in the n x n matrix
    for(i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)
    {
        num = !num;
        std::cout << " " << num;
        if(i%n == 0) {
            std::cout << "\n";      
            num = n%2 ? num : !num;  
        }
    }

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```